# Oracle : Materialized View vs Stored Procedure in terms of huge data at referesh time

Tags: oracle, plsql

My Materialized view underlying table is having 6M of records and its going for COMPLETE refresh each time. The MVIEW underlying query is having 18 table join(all table in the same schema). Its blocking the PGA memory each time when refresh happening and I am getting warning. So my question is below.

1) Shall I change the Materialized view to a stored procedure? Stored procedure will have the cursor with having same query as Mview and it will load the data to a new table by using BULK COLLECT and LIMIT 1000 rows at a time. We will write an Autosys job(daily once at non business hour) to call the procedure.

Below is my changed PROC:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_reporting IS

CURSOR cur_rows IS
(Old MVIEW query)

TYPE reporting_type IS TABLE OF reporting_test%ROWTYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
l_reporting_type reporting_type;

BEGIN

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE reporting_test';

OPEN cur_rows;
LOOP
   FETCH cur_rows BULK COLLECT INTO l_reporting_type LIMIT 1000;
   EXIT WHEN l_reporting_type.count = 0;

          BEGIN
            FORALL i IN l_reporting_type.FIRST .. l_reporting_type.LAST SAVE EXCEPTIONS
            INSERT INTO reporting_test VALUES (l_reporting_type(i).column_1 .. l_reporting_type(i).column_n);

          EXCEPTION
            WHEN ex_dml_errors THEN
              l_error_count := SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS.count;
              DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Number of failures: ' || l_error_count);
              FOR i IN 1 .. l_error_count 
              LOOP
                DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Error: ' || i || 
                  ' Array Index: ' || SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(i).error_index ||
                  ' Message: ' || SQLERRM(-SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(i).ERROR_CODE));
              END LOOP;
            END;

END LOOP;
CLOSE cur_rows;
END;
```

Comment: Materialized view and stored procedure are two different things. Are you saying you will use your stored procedure to write data to a table and use that table instead of the materialized view? Obviously a table doesn't support query rewrite whereas MV does. Ideally you should alter your MV to enable incremental refresh.

Comment: Have you run [DBMS_MVIEW.EXPLAIN_MVIEW()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_mview.htm#CEGGEHHC) to see whether you can tune the view to fast refresh?

Comment: Hi @Nick.McDermaid Yes, I will use stored procedure to write data to a table and use that table instead of the materialized view. My current MV has DISABLE QUERY REWRITE and also we don't want QUERY REWRITE to be ENABLE. I can not change the MV as incremental refresh as it has a UNION query (Select A UNION SELECT B).

Comment: I think you should try to tune the underlying query first. Optimize your joins to see the improvement. If still issue persists then you can try for BULK COLLECT and another TABLE.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid The underlying query of MVIEW is referring a VIEW. This VIEW is basically the join of table "A" and "A_HISTORY" table. These two tables are transaction tables and data is huge around 3.8M (A) & 22.3M (A_HISTORY). Apart from this its joining this VIEW to another 15 tables including A_HISTORY again. It leads to session PGA memory exceed alert. I changed VIEW to MVIEW and modified the main MVIEW to refer that MVIEW. By this approach transaction table joins data will be in physical table (MVIEW) & data will be less. Kindly review my approach & provide your valuable feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the underlying query of MVIEW and broken the MATVIEW query into two parts i.e two MVIEW. I moved all the one to one relationship table to the new MVIEW and made it fast refresh. We are refrencing the new MVIEW to the main MVIEW. By this approach, less data is getting loaded into PGA memory. We have made the new MVIEW to FAST load also to enhance the refresh mode. Now I am not getting warning of blocking the PGA memory.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that your first approach should be to examine the MView SQL for tuning.  If you have license for AWR, you can run it through the SQL Tuning Advisor.  Also please specify the PGA error, it may be that your DBA needs to increase pga_aggregate_target and/or pga_aggregate_limit.  In many cases, increasing the PGA and/or SGA provides a significant performance improvement, but I always try SQL tuning first.

Comment: The underlying query of MVIEW is referring a VIEW. This VIEW is basically the join of table "A" and "A_HISTORY" table. These two tables are transaction tables and data is huge around 3.8M (A) & 22.3M (A_HISTORY). Apart from this its joining this VIEW to another 15 tables including A_HISTORY again. It leads to session PGA memory exceed alert. I changed VIEW to MVIEW and modified the main MVIEW to refer that MVIEW. By this approach transaction table joins data will be in physical table (MVIEW) & data will be less. Kindly review my approach & provide your valuable feedback.

Comment: Any approach that reduces I/O and CPU resources needed to resolve the query will work.  In my experience it is sometimes worth it to go back to the original requirements for the query and armed with an understanding of the data model, see if there is a better/easier way to meet the requirements, as often times the original application views were set-up for different requirements and their use in the new requirements can become cumbersome. Further note on your approach: Mview of view introduces the complexity of refresh, and likely you will need index(es) on the new Mview.

Comment: Also basic to tuning:  subset the very large table as quickly in the process as possible.  You are, no doubt, familiar with "explain plan" (which shows the execution path that the Oracle optimizer will take) and other tuning tools [if not, then you will likely need to be].